# How do I integrate the "highchart editor" in react js web app?

Tags: highcharts, ckeditor5

I want to add the high chart editor into my existing ReactJS application. Can you give me some suggestions? I am trying to explore from last 1-week onwards but no results.

Is it possible to send a basic working example of a high chart editor with ReactJs?

Thank You

Comment: Hi @MVD Prasad, Have you checked the docs and examples with Highcharts Editor?  https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-editor

Comment: Thank You @ppotaczek, I have already checked that git repo and cloned into my local machine. But that app was not working getting errors like
 http://127.0.0.1:3005/src/core/highed.config.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
ckeditor:101 GET http://127.0.0.1:3005/gen_src/highed.meta.options.advanced.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
ckeditor:345 GET http://127.0.0.1:3005/plugins/json-import.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is there any wrapper for react-highchart-editor? Can you give me some examples in React? I want to integrate this highchart-editor into existing CKEditor